# Find all strings in a file that are the same and print the value after in perl

Tags: perl, printing, no-duplicates

Good Day guys.

I am trying to print from an excel file to a ini file, I have the excel and ini writing sorted, but my issue lies with getting the values without duplicating.

The excel file will contain something like this

```
    House        |     133_Anderson_str
    Shop         |     12_Smith_Str
    Wheelshop    |     832_Smith_Str
    House        |     21_smith_Str
    Shop         |     1191_dandelion_rd
```

If I do a foreach and print it to the ini file I will get a result like this

```
    [House]
    adress=133_Anderson_str

    [Shop]
    adress=12_Smith_Str

    [Wheelshop]
    address=832_Smith_Str

    [House]
    adress=21_smith_Str

    [Shop]
    address=1191_dandelion_rd
```

This cannot work because if I run the gui that will search for all adresses under house, it will only reference the first one and then end at the new line. I want to print each duplicate value once and then the next value after it should be printed like this

```
    [House]
    adress=133_Anderson_str, 21_smith_Str

    [Shop]
    adress=12_Smith_Str, 1191_dandelion_rd


    [Wheelshop]
    address=832_Smith_Str
```

I have tried a has table, but I cannot get to print in the correct order and make sure that each value gets printed to the correct key and without duplicating the key.

I am using Config::Inifiles to print and read the ini and SpreadSheet::Read to get the data from the spreadsheet.

Hope someone can show me the light!

Thanks a mill.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be `@input` array with 5 lines/elements,

```
House        |     133_Anderson_str
Shop         |     12_Smith_Str
Wheelshop    |     832_Smith_Str
House        |     21_smith_Str
Shop         |     1191_dandelion_rd
```

First, `%hash` is used to group elements of `@input` into hash of arrays structure,

```
my %hash;
for my $line (@input) {

  # $k = "House"; $v ="133_Anderson_str", etc.
  my ($k, $v) = split / [\s\|]+ /x, $line;

  my $arr = $hash{$k} ||= [];
  push @$arr, $v;
}
```

Now when grouping is done, proceed with output,

```
for my $k (sort keys %hash) {

  my $arr = $hash{$k};
  my $vals = join ", ", @$arr;

  print "[$k]\n", "address=$vals\n\n";
}
```

Comment: Damn, that is so simple. Thanks a million!!